# What are Hyperlinked APIs in Django REST framework?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

What exactly are hyperlinked APIs or hyperlinked fields in Django models? What scenarios or what sort of data do we save in hyperlinked fields? What are the use cases and cost of using this?

Comment: read [this](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/5-relationships-and-hyperlinked-apis/)

Comment: @YugandharChaudhari Thanks for the response. However my question is little different. The DRF documentation explains how to represent hyperlinked style entities but do not clarify on what exactly and why we need hyperlinked entities. Could you help me on understanding that.

Comment: According to my understanding our relationships are in the form of `id` or `primary key` in a model. Hyperlinking will generate hyperlink for that field lets say `ModelA`  has `ModelB` with `pk =1`  if we hyperlink then there will be link referencing to `ModelB` like `http://example/api/wdawwawda` that will make ModelB discoverable through link and improve cohesion i.e. `ModelA` viewed as whole with valid links instead of pks

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks a lot @YugandharChaudhari

Answer (score 2):

[Docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/5-relationships-and-hyperlinked-apis/) says

> Relationships within our API are represented by using
>   primary keys. Hyperlinking improve the cohesion
>   and discoverability of our API, by instead using hyperlinking for
>   relationships.

According to my understanding our relationships are in the form of id or primary key in a model.

Hyperlinking will generate hyperlink for that field lets say `ModelA` has `ModelB` with pk =1

If we hyperlink then there will be link referencing to `ModelB` like

`http://example/api/wdawwawda`

that will make `ModelB` discoverable through link and improve [cohesion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohesion_(computer_science))

i.e. ModelA viewed as whole with valid links instead of pks

[**Reference**](https://stormpath.com/blog/linking-and-resource-expansion-rest-api-tips)